# AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application:

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm using `msal` to authenticate user.

My `userAgentApplication` looks like this:

```
var userAgentApplication = new UserAgentApplication({
  auth: {
    clientId: config.appId,
    authority: config.authority,
    validateAuthority: false,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
  },
});
```

Here's my `config.js`

```
modules.exports = {
    appId: "<my-App-id>",
    authority:
      "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my-Tenant-id>/",
    scopes: ["user.read", "calendars.read"],
  };
```

I keep hitting this error and I have no idea why it's happened.

```
Request Id: 38b5b62e-0407-4520-8319-157b9c2e3e00
Correlation Id: 143c20c5-4cab-41be-aded-14daa783d022
Timestamp: 2020-04-06T07:21:35Z
Message: AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: 'xxxxxxxxxx'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake. In my case, I allow App Service to accept both http and https request.

It was http request so it didn’t match the call back URL. I basically just disabled http request from settings of App Service in Azure portal to make sure all incoming requests were https.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not set `auth.redirectUri` when you instantiate `UserAgentApplication`, `msal` will use the url of the current page as the `redirectUri` that is set for each request, and pages used as `redirectUri` must all be registered in the Azure Portal. You either need to set `auth.redirectUri` to a url that is registered in the Azure Portal, or register all the pages in your application as possible redirect uris (probably less preferable).